# Upgrading to Symfony 2.6 causes issue with ApplicationSonataUserExtension

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am currently trying to upgrade to Symfony 2.6. Everything went smoothly except that I got this error after running composer.phar update

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                                                                  
  Warning: Missing argument 1 for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration::__construct(), called in src/Application/Sonata/UserB  
  undle/DependencyInjection/ApplicationSonataUserExtension.php on line 23 and defined
```

However, there is no `__construct()` function in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration` ...

The code I have in `ApplicationSonataUserExtension.php` is :

```
<?php

namespace  Application\Sonata\UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class ApplicationSonataUserExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

I have really no clue...

Comment: Please, try to `var_dump($rootNode)` in `Configuration::getConfigTreeBuilder()`, somewhere on line 34-35, after it gets declarated. What it has in it?

Comment: I don't have that file under Application/Sonata/UserBundle/DependencyInjection

Comment: But you are using `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration`, right? And compared to version 2.5, 2.6 **does** have `__construct()` in it! http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.html#method___construct So, just try to add bool variable, say, TRUE, to `new Configuration()`. Like `new Configuration(TRUE)`.

Comment: That's probably the answer, thank you ! I don't know why when I was accessing the file, __construct was not there... anyway tahnk you !

Comment: Then I post it as an answer. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Symfony 2.5, 2.6 actually **has** `__construct()` method in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration`, and its argument represents debug mode, according to [this](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.html). So, adding bool variable to `Configuration` should solve the problem.

```
$configuration = new Configuration(TRUE); //or FALSE, if it's in prod
```

To get debug mode easily enough automatically, you could use something like:

```
$env = $container->getParameter("kernel.environment");
$debug = ( $env === 'dev' ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Comment: How do I make it easily true in debug and false in prod ?